# ERRO C++ IVALID OPERANDS TYPES 'FLOAT' and 'FLOAT' to binary 'operator+'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

float media (int n, float *vetor[]){
    float m = 0, soma = 0;
    
    //fazendo soma do vetor
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        soma = soma + vetor[i];
    }
    //calcular media
    m = soma / n;
    //retornar 
    return m;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n;
    float vetor[n];
    float mediaFinal;
    //Leitura das notas
    cout << "Informe o tamanho do vetor: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Preencha o vetor com " << n << " inteiros: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> vetor[n];
    }
    //Chamado do metodo
    mediaFinal = media(n, vetor);
    cout << "Media = " << mediaFinal;
    return 0;
}
```

Na hora de compilar na linha 13 apresenta o erro "invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float*' to binary 'operator+'", não sei como resolver.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Já arrumei não sabia mexer na plataforma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente, na sua função *media*, você está declarando que ela recebe como parâmetro basicamente uma matriz, ou você declara como:

```
float media (int n, float vetor[])
```

ou como:

```
float media (int n, float *vetor)
```

Segundo, no momento que você está lendo os dados:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> vetor[n];
    }
```

Você está atribuindo o valor da entrada apenas a uma posição do vetor, a posição *n*.

O esperado para que o vetor fosse populado posição a posição seria:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> vetor[i];
    }
```

No final o código ficaria similar a isso:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

float media (int n, float vetor[]){
    float m = 0, soma = 0;
    
    //fazendo soma do vetor
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        soma = soma + vetor[i];

    }
    //calcular media
    m = soma / n;
    //retornar 
    return m;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int n;
    float vetor[n];
    float mediaFinal;
    //Leitura das notas
    cout << "Informe o tamanho do vetor: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Preencha o vetor com " << n << " inteiros: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> vetor[i];
    }

    //Chamado do metodo
    mediaFinal = media(n, vetor);
    cout << "Media = " << mediaFinal;
    return 0;
}
```